# How to return a single attribute instead of all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Usually a query returns a user model array, but I want a name array. Is there some convenient way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
names = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['age > 10'], :select => 'name').collect {|obj| obj.name }
```

Comment: i'm a new on ruby is the collect function is the same as map?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Ruby 1.9 + Rails 3 way to do it.

```
names = User.select(:name).map(&:name)
```